# Unable to get metrics from PrometheusServlet on Databricks Spark 3.1.1

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, databricks

Trying to get prometheus metrics with grafana dashboard working for Databricks clusters on AWS but cannot seem to get connections on the ports as requried.  I've tried a few different setups, but will focus on PrometheusServlet in this question as it seems like it should be the quickest path to glory.

PrometheusServlet - I put this in my metrics.properties file using an init script on each worker:

```
sudo bash -c "cat <<EOF >> /databricks/spark/conf/metrics.properties
*.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
*.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/prometheus
master.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/master/prometheus
applications.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/applications/prometheus

# Enable jvm source for instance master, worker, driver and executor
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

EOF"
```

I also have "spark.ui.prometheus.enabled true" and "spark.executor.processTreeMetrics.enabled true" in the spark config options for the Databricks job

I get a connection refused when trying to hit the worker URL at anything but port 8080.  On port 8080 I get a wierd binary response "P%" when I try to connect via curl, and get a bad SSL cert error when I try to connect via the browser.  I've opened up the necessary ports on the security group associated with the Spark workers. Trying to add a worker in Grafana just results in a 'Bad Gateway' error.

Has anyone gotten the PrometheusServlet working on Databricks clusters? Is there another way I should be doing this? This is the blog I was following for reference, as the PrometheusServlet documentation is pretty hard to find: https://dzlab.github.io/bigdata/2020/07/03/spark3-monitoring-1/

I'm running Databricks 8.3 runtime, Spark 3.1.1.

Comment: Having similar problem, I'm keeping you in touch if I manage it :)

Comment: Hi Zyd and @arthur-clerc-gherardi, could you find out how to solve this?

Comment: @ArthurClerc-Gherardi I have not, I ended up giving up in order to focus on other projects.  I hope to get some time to revisit it soon, I feel like I was really close like just missing some network configuration but I really didn't know what else to try.

Comment: @zyd I might work on it in few weeks, I'll keep in touch

Comment: @ArthurClerc-Gherardi if you figure something out, please do reach out! very much appreciate you reaching out

Comment: One thing to be aware, depending on the configuration of the cluster, there might be asymmetric routing issues in play. In this case, no packets come back... Ended up using another agent to push the metrics out of databricks instead of scraping it